# Can I use set comprehension to create a list of dict from a bigger list of dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, set

I'm working with denormalized tables which provides a bit of challenge when it comes to extracting unique information.  If the tables were normalized:

```
unique_data = list({d['value'] for d in mydata})
```

would do the trick.

But the tables aren't normalized.

Can I create a set of dict that I can then turn into list?  Something like (this gives me an error):

```
unique_data_with_id = list({{'id':d['id'], 'value':d['value']} for d in mydata})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries are mutable, so you can't put them in a set.  One way around this is to use a `namedtuple` instead of a dictionary:

```
IdValueTuple = collections.namedtuple("IdValueTuple", "id value")
unique_data_with_id = list({IdValueTuple(d["id"], d["value"]) for d in mydata})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{'id':d['id'], 'value':d['value']} for d in mydata}
```

creates a `set` of`dict`s. Because `dict`s are mutable, they aren't hashable and a set needs hashable elements.

Try `tuple` instead:

```
{(d['id'], d['value']) for d in mydata}
```

Note that I quite like Sven Marnach's usage of a `namedtuple` here.

Answer (score 0):

More because it's occasionally useful in other contexts, you could use a `frozenset` as an intermediate object:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(mydata)
[{'id': 1, 'ignore': 92, 'value': 'a'},
 {'id': 2, 'ignore': 92, 'value': 'b'},
 {'id': 1, 'ignore': 92, 'value': 'a'}]
>>> keep_keys = "id", "value"
>>> [dict(s) for s in {frozenset((k, d[k]) for k in keep_keys) for d in mydata}]
[{'id': 1, 'value': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'b'}]
```